# Trying to get powershell working within C#/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, powershell-5.0

I was trying to learn how to use powershell within C#
I was following [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)

However when I run it I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create()
>      at desktopAdmin365.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ncox\source\repos\desktopAdmin365\Program.cs:line 11
>
> C:\Users\ncox\source\repos\desktopAdmin365\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\desktopAdmin365.exe (process 17464) exited with code -532462766.

I am sure I'm missing something when including references/dependencies from the solutions explorer but I am not having any luck with google finding out which one

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace desktopAdmin365
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance  = PowerShell.Create())
            { 
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("param($param1) $d = get-date; $s = 'test string value'; " +
                "$d; $s; $param1; get-service");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your dependencies in the project, you'll likely see a warning about the package being restored using .NETFramework and possibly not being compatible.

Your project is .NET core, so you might need to install Powershell Core instead.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6

Alternatively, switch to a .net framework solution and it will work.

Comment: I just spent a good while on google trying to find how to make it call powershell core instead of default power shell. Do you have a link that actually shows how to specify core over ps5?

Comment: @nicholascox2 https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/cmdlet-example/visual-studio-simple-example.md#building-a-c-cmdlet-for-powershell-core-with-visual-studio