# Running remote PowerShell script using .Net 5.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, powershell-remoting, .net-standard-2.0, powershell-core

The method call in C# is like this -

```
        public void GetKey()
        {
            WSManConnectionInfo connectioninfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
          
            var ss = new NetworkCredential("xxx.yyyy\\Administrator", "PassFail2Hehe");
            connectioninfo.ComputerName = "<some IP Address>";            
            connectioninfo.Credential = new PSCredential(ss.UserName, ss.SecurePassword);
          
            //Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectioninfo);
            //runspace.Open();
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var re = ps.AddScript("Get-Service");
                var results = re.Invoke();
            }
        }
```

I am using the NuGet package 'Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies 1.1.0', as it is showing as the recommended package in Visual Studio 2019 for resolving the types of "Runspace", "PowerShell" etc.

However, I am getting the exception when the instance of "Runspace" or "PowerShell" is created. The exception is like this - "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142405/trying-to-get-powershell-working-within-c-visual-studio) post and realized that I was getting the warning indeed for the NuGet package -

> "Package 'Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies 1.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

As per suggested in the post, I installed Powershell Core 7.1.3, but the warning and exceptions were not resolved. Then I switched to ".Net Standard 2.0", since it the project was a class library, but nothing changed. The same warning message and exception.

How can I make remote PowerShell call using ".Net Core 5.0" (or ".Net Standard 2.0") ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target .Net 5, the correct nuget package to use is [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK)